# Trigger update of UpdatePanel inside user control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, web-user-controls

Is there any way to trigger update of updatepanel inside a web user control through use of a property ? This does not work

```
public bool RefreshExclusions
{
    set
    {
        upnl1.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find update panel from your user control and call update method. like...

```
((UpdatePanel)Usercontrol.FindControl("updatePanelID")).Update();
```